# Error: distinct() must use existing variables

Tags: r, distinct

The data is taken from the post by Jesse Sadler
"Excel vs R: A Brief Introduction to R"
The code can be read as “create a data frame object called letters from the csv file named
correspondence-data-1585.csv.”

```
 letters <- read_csv("data/correspondence-data-1585.csv")
```

To begin we only need to load the tidyverse package, which includes the individual packages.

```
 library(tidyverse)

    letters
    # A tibble: 115 × 3
   `@@ -0`                 `0 +1`  `115 @@`          
   <chr>                   <chr>   <chr>             
 1 writer                  source  destination,date  
 2 Meulen, Andries van der Antwerp Delft,1585-01-03  
 3 Meulen, Andries van der Antwerp Haarlem,1585-01-09
 4 Meulen, Andries van der Antwerp Haarlem,1585-01-11
 5 Meulen, Andries van der Antwerp Delft,1585-01-12  
 6 Meulen, Andries van der Antwerp Haarlem,1585-01-12
 7 Meulen, Andries van der Antwerp Delft,1585-01-17  
 8 Meulen, Andries van der Antwerp Delft,1585-01-22  
 9 Meulen, Andries van der Antwerp Delft,1585-01-23  
10 Della Faille, Marten    Antwerp Haarlem,1585-01-24
    # … with 105 more rows
    # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

This tells us that letters is a tibble, which is a special kind of data frame meant to
work well in the tidyverse. Each letter has four pieces of information or variables:
the writer of the letter, the place from which it was sent, the place to which it was sent,
and the date sent. Below the column headings of writer, source, destination, and date
we are informed of the type of data for each variable. This shows that the first three
columns consist of character strings (chr), meaning that the data is words,
The function distinct() takes a data frame, followed by the name of the column that I
am interested in, returning a new data frame object with one column, which consists of
the unique values from the original column.

When applying the function "distinct()" I expect to get

```
distinct(letters, writer)
#> # A tibble: 12 × 1
#>    writer                        
#>    <chr>                         
#>  1 Meulen, Andries van der       
#>  2 Della Faille, Marten          
#>  3 Della Faille, Jacques         
#>  4 Staten van Brabant            
#>  5 Della Faille, Joris           
#>  6 Eeckeren, Robert van          
#>  7 Anraet, Thomas                
#>  8 Burgemeesters of Antwerp      
#>  9 Wale, Jan de                  
#> 10 Calvart, Jacques              
#> 11 Janssen van der Meulen, Peeter
#> 12 Noirot, Jacques
```

However I get an error.

```
> distinct(letters, writer)
Error in `distinct()`:
! Must use existing variables.
✖ `writer` not found in `.data`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Your column headings appear to be `@@ -0`, `0 +1`, `115 @@`, ... You should figure out how they got messed up.

Comment: Showing us  the first few lines of `data/correspondence-data-1585.csv` might explain things.

Comment: Do you get the right answer if you skip the first line when ijmporting the file? E.g. `letters <- read_csv("data/correspondence-data-1585.csv", skip = 1)`